# loadbalancing with --random option with iptables

Tags: iptables

I'm doing some loadbalancing testing with iptables by doing som portredirect on several ports on my server. i'm a bit curios how does the --random option work with the REDIRECT option?
is it using some kind of round robin algoritm? there doesn't seem to be any info about this in the man pages..

this is the iptable rule i'm using right now:
    -A PREROUTING -d 10.10.10.1/32 -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5000 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1194-1197 --random

also using this iptable rule will it take up alot of performance on the server? because I will have alot of traffic passing thorough the server.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution is truly random, and it should not eat many resources by itself.

I am afraid about the utility of this spreading. Do you have e.g. 4 CPUs and 4 processes, each one listening to one port in 1194-1197 range?